# I am trying to open DTS packages in SQL Server 2008 R2, but getting error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to open DTS packages in SQL Server 2008 R2. But I'm getting this following error

> sql server 2000 DTS Designer components are required to editDTS
>   Packages.install the special web download, " sql serevr 200 DTS
>   Designer Components" to use this feature
>   .(microsoft.sqlserver.dtsobjectexplorerUI)

Anybody help how to make it work?

As I already installed the `SQLServer2005_BC.msi` & `SQLServer2005_DTS.msi`

Comment: Is your 2008 R2 install 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do: SQL Server **2000** DTS Designer components are required. Install the **special web download SQL Server 2000 Designer Components**. What part of that isn't clear?

Comment: @KenWhite what part of "As I already installed ..." wasn't clear to you?

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker: If it were already installed (correctly), the error message wouldn't say they still needed to be installed. In addition, the filename says the poster installed **SQLServer2005_dts.msi**, and the error message clearly says **SQLServer2000**, so my **bolded** text in my comment is clear. What part of that isn't clear to you? (Just in case: One number ends in `5`, the other in `0`, the question title number ends in `8`.) :-) 2008 != 2005 != 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Your question subject says SQL Server **2008**, the error message says SQL Server **2000**, and you installed SQL Server **2005**'s MSI. You have three different versions of SQL Server in the three items.

You're trying to install something that either isn't the right version for the SQL Server version you're using (2008), or is no longer available or required for SQL Server 2008. You need to find the proper means of editing DTS files for SQL Server 2008, or research what replaced them in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you would kindly search for the topic before answering, you would know SQL Server 2008 does not have native support for DTS. To open/modify packages in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, you have to use the SQL Server 2000 Designer Components (SQLServer2005_DTS.msi) which requires SQL Server 2005 Backwards Compatability (SQLServer2005_BC.msi) to be installed. None of this works on a 64 bit install of SQL Server 2008. He will not be able to get it to work if he is working with a 64 bit install.

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker: The question asked here wasn't about that; instead of being so snarky and rude, kindly read the actual question. It was about a specific error message, and I answered that question. If you'd like to post a different one, please feel free to do so. If you read the [help] and [about] pages, you'll see that we ask for **specific** questions here, and then provide **specific** answers to those questions. It's not my job to determine whether 2008 supports it; it's my task to answer the question the poster asked here. He will not get 2000/2005 packages to work on 2008 at all.

Comment: Microsoft explicitly states that DTS is optionally supported in 2008, but only for 32 bit installs. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440(v=sql.105).aspx Please do not provide incorrect information claiming it as truth.

Comment: @Matthew: I provided **NO** information that said any such thing. "research what replaced them in SQL Server 2008". It appears you have a severe reading comprehension problem and don't understand words that are in front of you. Now please stop commenting on this three year old thread, at least until you can understand the words.